# Filter DataGridView across all columns

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Sorry for my bad English. I am an old German man, I want to filter a DGV across all columns. In the Moment I use following filter:

```
Dim Such_Spalte = Me.DtS_DGV.DTT_1.article_1Column.ColumnName
```

But I have 10 Columns (article_1 to Article_10)

If as an example Sugar is in column 1,3,5 I want to see all records where sugar occurs.

I hope this is understandable

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using strongly typed datasets and as such I would expect that your datagridview is bound through a BindingSource (the windows forms designer sets it up this way, and my presumption is that you used te designer to do your binding)

If your datagridview is indeed bound through a bindingsource:

```
Dim bs = DirectCast(datagridviewX.DataSource, BindingSource)

Dim sb = New StringBuilder() 'it will hold the filter string

For Each col in DtS_DGV.DTT_1.Columns
  sb.AppendFormat("[{0}] = '{1}' OR ", col.ColumnName, "Sugar")
Next col

sb.Length -= 3 'remove the trailing OR

bs.Filter = sb.ToString()
```

If your datagridview is bound direvtly to the table, it will have attached to the table's `DefaultView` property, a DataView, which also has a Filter that works in the same way. If this is the case, do the same thing with the loop to build the filter string, and then:

```
DtS_DGV.DTT_1.DefaultView.Filter = sb.ToString()
```